# Should we escape or not escape the double quotes living in an HTML tag inside a YAML file?

Tags: escaping, double, yaml, double-quotes

I'm a bit confused about whether we should escape or not the double quotes inside an HTML tag inside a YAML file.

`playing_with_cards_html: Playing your best game with %{card_type} between now and <span class="best-card">%{worst_card}</span>.`

It looks a valid YAML, but if we add escaping characters for the double quote:

`playing_with_cards_html: Playing your best game with %{card_type} between now and <span class=\"best-card\">%{worst_card}</span>.`

Would it still render correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably not render correctly, unless the program that loads the YAML does some backslash escaping on the loaded string.

The value for the key `playing_with_cards_html` is a [plain scalar](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2788859). 
Within such scalars no backslash escaping is defined: every characters is taken as it is. Therefor the second version of the URL actually has two extra characters (both being `\`), and that probably doesn't render as you want.

Backslash escaping in YAML, is only possible if the scalar itself is [double quoted](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2787109) (i.e. starts and ends with a double quoted). And in that case you *have to* escape any double quotes in mid-scalar with a backslash.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Anthon! :)